# Does the fermentation of batter increase its weight?

Tags: mass, physical-chemistry, air, food

Indian dishes like the [Idli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idli) and the [Dosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosa) are prepared from a fermented batter composed of mainly rice and black grams. (See [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3551127/) for more information on the preparation.)

Would the fermentation process of the batter result in an increase of its total mass? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

That is unlikely. Fermentation breaks down carbohydrates, which releases carbon dioxide which in part escapes into the air. The batter will hence lose mass. (There may be complications from water condensing or drying from the batter.)

Comment: There may also a small increase from the airborn yeasts and bacteria making its way through the dough, but that is certainly negligible compared to the carbon dioxide released and the evaporation of water.